# Select dropdown color changing

Tags: html, css

I have created a sample dropdown list (the code is below). I want to change the font color of the "Pick a Country" which is displaying in the select option: The default text color is black and I want to change it to red.

```
<select id="select-id">
<option value="" selected="">Pick a Country</option>
<option value="">India</option>
<option value="">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="">Sweden</option>
```

Comment: You need to integrate JavaScript/Jquery script for this task. I think you want to show  red color only for selected country?

Comment: @ ZenOut ,I want to change the color of the text pick a country on which we use to click to get dropdown options, Hope you understood my concern

Comment: You can not style `option`s cross browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe below solution gets what you want. Just few lines of CSS (explanation below snippet)

#### Warning

Styling `<select>` and `<option>` elements is not supported across all browsers, because they are rendered by OS, not browser. There are external libraries that create select-like elements composed from HTML elements that can be styled. Below solution is not 100% safe.

#### Snippet

```css
#select-id {
  color: red;
}

#select-id option:not(:checked) {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-id">
  <option value="" selected="">Pick a Country</option>
  <option value="">India</option>
  <option value="">Sri Lanka</option>
  <option value="">Sweden</option>
</select>
```

#### Explanation

```
#select-id {
  color: red;
}
```

Makes select and all options have `color: red`.

```
#select-id option:not(:checked) {
  color: initial;
}
```

Makes not-selected options have initial color, which is black.

Comment: Andrzej Ziółek, thank you for your answer, but i want to change the color of the text pick a country on which we use to click to get dropdown options, Hope you  understood my concern

Comment: I updated my snippet. Does it solve your problem now?

Comment: Have you tested this? Try it on a Mac. It will not work in either Chrome or Safari.

Comment: I have. Working on Chrome right now.

Comment: On a Mac? I don't believe you. You can not style `option`s cross browser.

Comment: Sure, will add annotation, but I don't think OP wanted cross-browser-multi-functional solution with external plugin.

Comment: thank you so much  Andrzej Ziółek, its working fine as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can either style the first option or you can apply a class to it.

With first selector:

```
#select-id option:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

With class selector:

```
 #select-id .placeholder {
   color: red;
 }
```

Comment: hello furkan, its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select option:first-child{
    color: red;
}
```